# Counting a specific word within cell range based on what another cell range says

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to gather information on common themes for reviews. I have the content of the review in one column and the rating 1-5 in another. I want to be able to count how many times certain words appear in one column based on what the star rating is another. I am using this formula to count but cannot figure out how to add the second column factor. Sometimes I am only counting for one word sometimes more than once hence the word1/2 difference.

```
=SUM((LEN(G2:G190)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2:G190,"word1","")))/LEN("word1")+(LEN(G2:G190)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2:G190,"word2","")))/LEN("word2"))
```

example of the table I am describing for visual
[image]

I want to be able to use this or another formula to say word1 and word2 appears 56 times when the star rating in the other column shows less than 4.

I have attempted to make it a sumif formula to add the if condition but I cant seem to get the logic right to not throw an error. I am not sure if that is even the right route to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula works in my Excel 2013 sheet. Enter the formula as an arrayformula with ctrl+shift+enter if you don't work with Office 365 or Excel for the web or Excel 2021. In the example the formula counts how many times the words from cells F1 and F2 occur in cells B4 and B5. B3 is excluded because A3 isn't less than 5.

```
=SUM((LEN(IF(A3:A5<5,B3:B5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A3:A5<5,B3:B5),F1,"")))/LEN(F1),(LEN(IF(A3:A5<5,B3:B5))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(IF(A3:A5<5,B3:B5),F2,"")))/LEN(F2))
```

[image: Counting a specific word within cell range based on what another cell range says]